# How to send POST data with an <a> tag using a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-post

So I have something like this

```
<li><a href="new/page">Something</li>
<li><a href="#">Something else</li>
```

I want to be able to click one of the items, and send the current URL with so I can get it in the new page. I cannot store the current URL in the session because I will be going to a different location that doesn't have the same session. This is why I think that I want to have some sort of POST data so I can just send the URL or location along with it. I would like to keep it an `<a>` tag because that is how the style is set.

Comment: You want to send the current url to your new page?

Comment: You'd need javascript to intercept the click on the `<a>` and then convert everything to a post. But what makes you think you need a POST? You can include query parameters in the url e.g. `<a href="new/page?foo=bar">`

Comment: Use js prevent default and send using post method

Comment: you could also use a `<form>` and call `form.submit` from the `<a>`'s click handler if you really need POST.

Comment: @MarcB Yes maybe I don't need a post. How would I make the javascript construct that? If you put that as an answer with a little more to it, that might be the one.

Comment: construct what? it's just a link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `<a href="new/page?variable=data">`. When you are ready to extract the variable on another page, you can use something like this:

```
var myData = getQueryVariable("variable");

if(myData){
  console.log(myData);//to verify it
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("?");

  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  console.log('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
```

Comment: This worked, and I am able to get the variable on the new page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET solution from PHP:

```
<li><a href="new/page?from=<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>" Something</li>
```

Maybe you can also rely on info from the http-referer headline.

Comment: $PHP_SELF didn't actually get anything. I used $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; and it worked